# Sync Facebook/Twitter posts with Google+

Tags: facebook, twitter, google-plus, automation

My business uses a Facebook page to post all of their updates on, which (I'm told) are also automatically posted to Twitter. I have just set up a Google+ page for the business, and I would like the posts from the Facebook page to sync with the Google+ page as they do for Twitter.

Switching origin of the updates from Facebook to Google+ is currently **not an option** as the person in change of posting these updates is used to using Facebook and not really prepared to change. Also, it would be great if all old posts are added to Google+ as well.

Comment: Would it be okay to daisy-chain them? There are several solutions here for auto-posting from Twitter to Google+.

Comment: That would be fine, I guess. The main restriction is that Facebook needs to remain the main point for posting updates

Comment: I think the order is G+ > Twitter > Facebook..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google+ API is read only at the moment. Google is working with select partners to provide the Page API which allows writing to the page. You may be able to work with one of these partners (see http://www.google.com/+/business/3rdpartytools.html) to get what you need.

You can also request access to this API at https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup, however there is no indication when, or even if, they would grant you access if you apply for it using this page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm more looking for a pre-built application to suit my needs, not the means of creating one

Comment: Check out the applications and services listed at http://www.google.com/+/business/3rdpartytools.html to see if any of them suit your needs.

Answer (score 6):

Google+ API is currently read only. So no automated posting is possible right now. You have to wait till Google lets people create posts via API.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I am aware of the official status, and 'm hoping that there still is a method. I've heard that Google has given some companies early access to the full API

Comment: No way to bypass it yet. And yes, Google is experimenting more open API with only selected partners. No way we can apply and get that.

Answer (score 2):

I've done in this way:

Facebook → IFTTT recipe that triggers on Buffer → Buffer (set to post every 15 minutes) → Google+

It works from Facebook page to Google+ page.

Answer (score 1):

[magentariver.com/dash](http://magentariver.com/dash) is a free service that mirrors Google Plus activity on Facebook. It also provides RSS feed for IFTTT. Google Plus Pages and Facebook pages are supported as well!  The Crosspost service has been recently upgrated and now supports posting to Facebook and Twitter too.

It also trasfers newly posted photo albums from Google Plus to Facebook in full.

Comment: This is really great, but I'm looking for a way to send posts on Facebook *to* Google+, not the other way round

Comment: This would be a natural way of doing things, but unfortuantely Google is being difficult and does not allow this.

Comment: Which is why I have upvoted this, but I cannot accept it as it does not fulfill the requirements of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dlvr.it to cross-post stuff between Twitter, Facebook and Google+ Pages. They however require you to subscribe to a premium plan. The other option is HootSuite which is free.

Answer (score 0):

[Buffer](http://bufferapp.com) has released support for posting to Google+ pages. Combine this with [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com) for adding Facebook or Twitter posts to your buffer, and you have a working solution.